# Find the maximum distance between two series in a chart

Tags: c#, charts, distance, mschart, series

I have got a chart with two series. Now I want to find the maximum distance between the chats along the x-axis in a given interval. To solve the problem the calculation of the distatance on a given x-point like in the picture at x=50 would be enough.

[image: distance between two datapoints]

I have got the following code:

```
public void MaxSpacing(object chart, int series1, int series2) 
{
    Chart tmpChart = (Chart)chart;
    double distance = 0;
    int positon = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tmpChart.Series[series1].Points.Count(); i++)
    {
        if ((Math.Abs(tmpChart.Series[series1].Points[i].YValues[0] - tmpChart.Series[series2].Points[i].YValues[0])) > distance)
        {
            distance = tmpChart.Series[series1].Points[i].YValues[0] - tmpChart.Series[series2].Points[i].YValues[0];
        }
}
```

The Problem about this code is, that it uses the Datapoints of both series. If the amount/interval  of points in series1 and series2 differs the calculation does not work. So I am looking vor the Y-values on a given X-value to calculate the distance.

Comment: sounds like linear interpolation, just connect lines through the dots. you could do more fancy like parabolas (spline fitting), but chances are that linear interpolation is good enough.

Comment: From what I can tell, you want to find the largest difference in Y values given two X values. I think that this means that the two points you are inspecting must have the same X value. So, compare the number of points in each series, and loop over the points in the series with the least amount of points. Also make sure that the two points you compare have the same X value. // If you want to get fancy you could use a regression technique to find the "missing" X values from the series with less points, then use the function from the regression to produce a Y value and then compare.

Comment: Are you saying you want to handle cases where the number of data points aren't the same between the two series? That you want to interpolate between two points if needed, to come up with a value to compare to the other series?

Comment: I don't get "Points[i].YValues[0]" How does a point have multiple y-values?

Comment: @Dennis_E in this case every Point i has one y-value and there are two sereies so you have got two y-values that you can subtract

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf have you got some code for the interpolation

Comment: @Dennis_E The charting package supports multiple y-values for each data point. Allows you to have variable-sized columns and such. Only 1 y value used in line plots like this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that you want to do some sort of interpolation between points if the two series do not have the same number of points. A simple linear interpolation should work for a sufficiently large number of points, and so the whole algorithm could look something like this (in pseudo-code):

```
double distance = 0;
Series series1 = tmpChart.Series[series1];
Series series2 = tmpChart.Series[series2];
Series seriesToEnumerate = series1.Points.Count() >= series2.Points.Count() ? series1 : series2;

for (int i = 0; i < series1.Count(); ++i)
{
    DataPoint point1 = series1.Points[i];
    DataPoint point2 = series2.Points[i];

    if (point1.X == point2.X)
    {
        distance = Math.Abs(point1.Y - point2.Y) // if greater than previous distance
    }
    else
    {
        // find two points in series2 whose X values surround point1.X, call them point3 and point4

        // Interpolate between point3 and point4 to find the y value at the x of point1
        double slope = (point4.Y - point3.Y) / (point4.X - point3.X);
        double intercept = point4.Y - slope * point4.X;
        double y2 = slope * point1.X + intercept;

        distance = Math.Abs(point1.Y - y2); // if this is greater than previous distance
    }
}
```

That's a simple example of an algorithm. You'll want to clean it up, do some error checking, make it more efficient, etc.

Comment: sorry but your example do not work at many points (for example you can't convert Charting.DataPoint into Drawing.Point `point1 = series1.Points[i];` )

Comment: The code I gave above is pseudo-code - it is not to be simply copy-pasted and compiled. You need to turn it in to actual c# code that compiles. `point1` and `point2` are `DataPoint` objects; I've edited the answer to make it a little more clear.

Comment: Ok, it just looked a bit more like c# than pseudo-code that is why I was writing that.

Answer (score 1):

If the x-values are not equal, increase the smaller one.
(This is probably not the most efficient way; it's just to explain the principle)

```
public void MaxSpacing(object chart, int series1, int series2)
{
    Chart tmpChart = (Chart)chart;
    double distance = 0;
    int position = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tmpChart.Series[series1].Points.Count(); i++) {
        if ((Math.Abs(tmpChart.Series[series1].Points[i].YValues[0] - tmpChart.Series[series2].Points[i].YValues[0])) > distance) {
            distance = tmpChart.Series[series1].Points[i].YValues[0] - tmpChart.Series[series2].Points[i].YValues[0];
        }
    }

    int len1 = tmpChart.Series[series1].Points.Count(), len2 = tmpChart.Series[series2].Points.Count();
    for (int i1 = 0, i2 = 0; i1 < len1 && i2 < len2;) {
        var x1 = tmpChart.Series[series1].Points[i1].XValue;
        var x2 = tmpChart.Series[series2].Points[i2].XValue;
        if (x1 < x2) {
            i1++;
        } else if (x2 < x1) {
            i2++;
        } else {
            double d = Math.Abs(tmpChart.Series[series1].Points[i1].YValues[0] - tmpChart.Series[series2].Points[i2].YValues[0]);
            if (d > distance) {
                distance = d;
                position = i1; //I'm guessing here
            }
            i1++;
            i2++;
        }
    }

}
```